# Tcl/NX passing objects as parameters

Tags: tcl

I am trying to pass an object to a method that sets it as a property for a new object. This is my code so far:

```
   nx::Class create Node {}


   nx::Class create Edge {
        :property node1:::Node
        :property node2:::Node
   }

   nx::Class create Graph {
    :variable edges {}

    :public method add {newNode1 newNode2} {
        ::Edge create newEdge -node1 $newNode1 -node2 $newNode2 
       }
    }
```

I am having trouble passing actual objects to this add method.

```
    ::Node create n1
    ::Node create n2 


    ::Graph create G
    G add n1 n2
```

Tells me that the edge creation expected an object but got "n1". When I try to dereference n1 and n2 with $n1 and $n2 I get "can't read ::n1 no such variable". Not really sure when the proper time to dereference is here, or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like some sort of command resolution issue. (The version with `$` is definitely wrong.) Try using `::n1` instead of `n1`…

Comment: Also, if that's what the bug is then definitely report it as a bug in NX. It ought to resolve objects in the global namespace if they're not found locally; that's how the rest of Tcl works for command resolution _precisely_ to avoid this sort of evil case.

Comment: Actually, this code works. I removed the namespace for readability and that seemed to be the problem.